# Java - Why does 0 % 3 return 0?

Tags: java, math, modulo

I recently stumbled across this issue whilst programing. I wonder how this is possible, as modulo returns the remainder of the euclidean division a / b. Doesn't this mean that it would have to return 3 since returning 0 would mean that you have to perform a division by 0, which is impossible? Also, how is this handled in other programming languages? I know that modulo has very varying implementations throughout different languages, but is this a variable aspect or is it set by some mathematical statement?

Comment: How is modulo handled differently across languages when it is a mathematical concept? Can you give an example of such a difference?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Different languages do handle the sign of the operands differently. Check out the chart on the right side of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation

Comment: This question appears to be built on a number of incorrect assumptions.  Perhaps you would like to re-phrase the question.

Comment: The question gets 6 downvotes and the answer gets 12 upvotes. geeze

Comment: @ug_ +1.. I don't like it either. I've given quite a few answers that had ten times the thought in them that this one had and got a tenth of the votes...

Answer (score 18):

> Doesn't this mean that it would have to return 3 since returning 0 would mean that you have to perform a division by 0

No. You're not dividing 3 by 0, you're dividing 0 by 3, which of course yields a modulus of 0.

Answer (score 7):

If `a % b` is the remainder of `a / b`, then `0 % 3` must be the remainder of `0 / 3`. Since `0 / 3 = 0`, there is no remainder. There is no division by zero.